# Groovy swap string in capturing group

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to swap part of a string in groovy when Jenkins runs the pipeline. This is what I have:

```
def secrets = [
    'abc-${env}'      : [secret('my-api', 'MY_API_URL')],
    'xyz${my_env}kv'  : [secret('my-other-api', 'MY_OTHER_API_URL')
]
```

The `env` variable next to `abc` seems to get swapped out correctly but the `my_env` inbetween `xyz` and `kv` does not.

Jenkins gives me this error:

> Caused:
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.azurekeyvaultplugin.AzureKeyVaultException:
>   Failed to retrieve secret my-other-api from vault https://xyz
>   ${my_env}kv.vault.azure.net/, error message: named capturing group is
>   missing trailing '}'

Any ideas why the `my_env` is not getting replaced?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use a string with interpolated `${my_env}` variable. To make it working you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes. For instance, if the `my_env` variable is set to `dev`, then the following construction:

```
def secrets = [
    "abc-${env}"      : [secret('my-api', 'MY_API_URL')],
    "xyz${my_env}kv"  : [secret('my-other-api', 'MY_OTHER_API_URL')]
]
```

will produce a map like:

```
def secrets = [
    'abc-dev': [secret('my-api', 'MY_API_URL')],
    'xyzdevkv': [secret('my-other-api', 'MY_OTHER_API_URL')]
]
```

*(Single quotes always mean a regular Java string, while double quotes with a variable inside are compiled to a GString, and the variable gets interpolated correctly.)*